# Plugin not found/invalid plugin error while creating VBO custom action

Tags: views, 9, actions

I am creating VBO custom action and I constantly see the below error:

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "publish_TR_action" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\Action\ActionManager are: node_export_action, comment_unpublish_by_keyword_action, entity_delete_action:comment, node_assign_owner_action, node_unpromote_action, node_promote_action, node_make_sticky_action, node_unpublish_by_keyword_action, node_make_unsticky_action, bulk_node_export, user_add_role_action..........
```

under the module folder I have the below file : /web/modules/custom\mymod/config/install/system.action.publish_comment_action.yml

```
   langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - comment
id: publish_TR_action
label: 'Publish comment and create the T&R'
type: ""
plugin: publish_TR_action
configuration: {  }
```

Next, I made a action class under /src/plugin folder: web/modules/custom/mymod/src/Plugin/Action/PublishTRAction.php

```
   <?php

namespace Drupal\mymod\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\views_bulk_operations\Action\ViewsBulkOperationsActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;

/**
 * create custom action
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "node_export_action",
 *   label = @Translation("Export Content"),
 *   type = "node"
 * )
 */

class PublishTRAction extends ViewsBulkOperationsActionBase {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute($entity = NULL) {
    // Do some processing..

    // Don't return anything for a default completion message, otherwise return translatable markup.
    return $this->t('Some result');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($object, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
    if ($object->getEntityType() === 'node') {
      $access = $object->access('update', $account, TRUE)
        ->andIf($object->status->access('edit', $account, TRUE));
      return $return_as_object ? $access : $access->isAllowed();
    }

    // Other entity types may have different
    // access methods and properties.
    return TRUE;
  }

}
```

I uninstalled the module and while re-installing I see the above error. Any help??!
I am using Drupal 9.

Comment: In your php file you're declaring `"id = node_export_action"`, should be `"id = publish_TR_action"` instead.

Comment: worked!!! Thanks! can you add this as answer pls?!